# How to center image and float text on left and right?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to center an image and then float text (or buttons) to the left and right as it's wireframed below:

[image]

I know you can't `float: center;` and from a quick web search every recommended solution is a bit of a hack. So how could I setup the css for this specific situation? I'm using Twitter Bootstrap for whatever that's worth (probably nothing in this case).

Comment: Are you familiar with absolute positioning? Would that work in your case?

Answer (score 3):

You can `float: left` all the 3 column with percentage widths. Something like this:

```css
#col1, #col2, #col3 {
     float: left;
} 

#col1, #col3 {
    width: 25%;
}

#col2 {
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Also, if you are using Twitter Bootstrap you may want to use the [Fluid Grid System](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem) with 3 columns.

Comment: Thanks this works, but is difficult to implement because the number of responses (text bubbles) can vary. So I need to add logic to check and create new rows if the number of responses is > 2. If there are more than two responses then the second row becomes ugly to implement...

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you can work with a fixed width for the image. Then you can use `postion: absolute` and a negative `margin` to center the image.
Then  you can alternatively `float` the reactions to either side.

Here's how it looks in a mockup:
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/woestijnrog/ZdE86/)

You might need to set a minimum height for the container: If there are no reactions he will collapse completely, ignoring the image/middle column.

A maximum width for the reactions might also be necessary. Then they will fit in the open space to the sides.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not care about the responsiveness of your design and the container and centered image sizes are constant (independent on viewport), then you can just absolute position all the elements:

```
<div style="position: relative;">
  <div style="position: absolute; top: HEIGHT_OF_THE_VIEWPORT_MINUS_HEIGHT_OF_THE_IMAGE_DIVIDED_BY_2; left: WIDTH_OF_THE_VIEWPORT_MINUS_WIDTH_OF_THE_IMAGE_DIVIDED_BY_2;">
    <img src="..." />
  </div>
</div>
```

In responsive layout you will have to deal with unknown size of the container and unknown size of the centered picture.

You can center horizontal easily with `text-align: center;` and `margin: 0 auto;` styles.

Centering vertically in CSS is tricky part. You can use `display: table;` and `vertical-align: middle;` ("table method") but you will have problems with Internet Explorer. "Negative margin" and "positioning" methods works in IE. Searching for "vertical align css" in Google shown many useful discussions, but I recommend combination of the two prior methods (see [this article](http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html)) which works for good browsers and also IE >= 6:

```
<div style="display: table; height: 400px; #position: relative; overflow: hidden;">
  <div style=" #position: absolute; #top: 50%;display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
    <div class="greenBorder" style=" #position: relative; #top: -50%">
      some<br/>
      content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The trick is to mix the IE part with the "others" part in the way, that styles not to be read by IE are prefixed with `#`.

Note that this way you will adjust to different size of container, but the centered image will not change its size responsively.

Good method (simple and portable) is to use centered image as the background. Try using:

```
#row {
  background-image: url(img/image.png);
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

css with bootstraps layout separating left center and right columns (`#col1`, `#col2` and `#col3`).
You will get the image centered both horizontally and vertically.

*Update*: Background method does not allow to shrink the image responsively if you do not want it to scale up (enlarge) :(